# Providing Credentials to Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to put together a hello world program for testing out Google Cloud Storage. My goal is to have the simplest possible program that just uploads a hard-coded file to Cloud Storage.

I've been scouring the internet for a basic tutorial, but the closest I could find is [this guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java#google-cloud-storage-ga) for using Cloud Storage from App Engine. I've put together this program:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.google.cloud.storage.Acl;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Acl.Role;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Acl.User;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("my-file.txt");

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

        BlobInfo blobInfo =
            storage.create(
                BlobInfo
                    .newBuilder("my-cloud-storage-bucket", "my-file.txt")
                    .setAcl(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Acl.of(User.ofAllUsers(), Role.READER))))
                    .build(),
                fileInputStream);

        String fileUrl = blobInfo.getMediaLink();

        System.out.println("Uploaded URL: " + fileUrl);
    }
}
```

When I run that code, I get a `401 Unauthorized` error when I call `storage.create()`, and that's not surprising because I'm not providing a username or password. I gather that's because the example is running in App Engine, which provides the credentials that way.

I've tried passing in my credentials via a properties file:

```
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId("accountId")
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new File("PRIVATE_KEY_PATH"))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

Storage storage = new StorageOptions.DefaultStorageFactory().create(StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credential).build());
```

But that doesn't compile because the `setCredentials()` function needs a `Credentials` instance, not a `Credential` instance.

I've been Googling and reading through the [Cloud Storage API](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.21.1/apidocs/index.html), but I still can't figure out how I'm supposed to pass in the credentials without going through a convoluted setup process.

So, **my question is:** what is the simplest way to provide credentials to Google Cloud storage to upload a file?

For some background: I'm trying to compare and contrast Google Cloud Storage and Amazon S3. I can create a program like this in S3 no problem, but for some reason I'm hitting a brick wall with Cloud Storage. Definitely appreciate any insights or basic tutorials anybody can throw my way.

Comment: See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-java.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems it's not so easy to create credentials from a PKCS #12 file with new Google Cloud Client Library as it used to be with the old 
[Cloud Storage JSON API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1).

The easiest way would be to use JSON format instead as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts), and then use [`GoogleCredentials#fromStream`](http://google.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.7.1/apidocs/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html#fromStream(java.io.InputStream)) method to load it:

```
Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("credentials.json"));
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

If you still want to use PKCS #12, I believe this would work:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(
    SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), new FileInputStream("credentials.p12"), "notasecret", "privatekey", "notasecret");
Credentials credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials(null, "accountId", privateKey, null, null);
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is `"notasecret"` and `scopes` in your code snippet?

Comment: I looked it up in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/SecurityUtils) and it looks like those are passwords for the key file? My file is not password protected so I tried `PrivateKey privateKey = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), new FileInputStream("MyWebApp.json"), null, null, null);`, but that gives me a NPE at `SecurityUtils.java:82`. Any idea what I should use for those parameters?

Comment: @CatGrass If you generated the credentials from the Google Cloud Console, you shouldn't change those parameters. `notasecret` is the actual password Google uses: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#serviceaccounts

Comment: I tried this: `PrivateKey privateKey = SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.getPkcs12KeyStore(), new FileInputStream("MyWebApp.json"), "notasecret", "private_key", "notasecret");` but I get this error: `java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 123
 at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:847)
 at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1915)
 at KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
 at SecurityUtils.loadKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:82)
 at SecurityUtils.loadPrivateKeyFromKeyStore(SecurityUtils.java:115)`

Comment: As I wrote in my answer if you have the credentials in JSON format, use `GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyWebApp.json"))` to load them. The code snippet I posted is in case you have P12 format, which I assumed was the case because you were using the method `setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File` in the question.

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

The [Google Cloud client library for Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java) allows you to use several auth schemes, but by far the easiest is to take advantage of "[Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)." These are the credential associated with the service account that your app engine app runs as. If you use the google-cloud Java client library on App Engine or Compute Engine, the following should just work:

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobId;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BlobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;

Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob_name");
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(UTF_8));
```

This is probably the simplest way to use auth. If you're running the program locally and not deployed to a Google environment, you can also install the `gcloud` command line utility and then run `gcloud auth application-default login`, at which point application default credentials should enable the code above to authenticate as you without any explicit authentication logic.

If you want to programmatically specify a specific service account and have the JSON key file associated with it, you can do so explicitly like so:

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
    .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
         new FileInputStream("/path/to/my/key.json")))
    .build()
    .getService();
```

You can also specify the path to the service account private key by using the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. So something like:

```
$> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json java MyApp
```