# Google Doc AI Java SDK batchProcessDocumentsAsync produces "UNAUTHENTICATED" error with location=eu and FixedCredentialsProvider

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, sdk, cloud-document-ai

I'm following the code example from Google Document AI code examples to make an async processing request through the Java SDK here: https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#documentai_process_document-java

The only difference I have added is:

```
DocumentProcessorServiceSettings ss = DocumentProcessorServiceSettings
                .newBuilder()
                .setCredentialsProvider(
                        FixedCredentialsProvider.create(
                                GoogleCredentials.fromStream(
                                        new FileInputStream(adcLocation)
                                )
                        )
                )
                .setEndpoint(endpoint)
                .build();
```

What I have done here to introduce:

1. Credentias Provider - specifically an ADC json file.
2. Endpoint as a variable - this is because some of my processors are in the EU location.

If I were using the default endpoint **documentai.googleapis.com:443**, then it works. However, for processors hosted in the EU location, I would get the following:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid location: 'eu' must match the server deployment 'us'
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:588)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:567)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:91)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:66)
    at com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.getName(OperationFutureImpl.java:136)
```

So I assumed that I had to change my endpoint as well. So I changed it to **eu-documentai.googleapis.com:443** and then got this:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:588)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:567)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:91)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:66)
    at com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.getName(OperationFutureImpl.java:136)
```

So what could be wrong?

I've also tried to submit the same request via Postman, but it worked with both **documentai.googleapis.com** and **eu-documentai.googleapis.com** and the same ADC - except that in Postman, I did the `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` before copying and pasting it in the Bearer token.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include the location as part of the endpoint for the client if you're using processors outside of "us". (Which means that if you're using multiple processors across regions in the same code, you'll need to use multiple clients.)

---

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556477/6216983) for the credentials. You can use the `.setCredentials()` method instead of `.setCredentialsProvider()`.

Try something like this:

```java
Credentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
    .fromStream(new FileInputStream("credentials.json"));

DocumentProcessorServiceSettings ss = DocumentProcessorServiceSettings
    .newBuilder()
    .setCredentials(credentials)
    .build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, for some reason the ```DocumentProcessorServiceSettings``` class in my package does not have the method ```setCredentials()```. 
My ```google-cloud-document-ai``` version is ```2.19.0```

Comment: I'll keep looking into this. You're using the example that's shown in the client library docs, so not sure why it wouldn't be working. The settings object is being passed to the client creation method, correct?
You can also try using implicit authentication with application default credentials.
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/client-libraries#java

Comment: 1) Yes - The settings object is passed to the client creation method just as in the example. 
2) Implicit auth works fine! I think this is likely a problem with how the SDK builds the request, because it works in Postmen with the same endpoints and credentials.